# Prove that $G=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|=1\}$ is an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers, abelian-groups

Prove that $G=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|=1\}$ is an Abelian group with the multiplication operation of complex numbers. In other words, we want to prove that:
$$\begin{align}
    &(G_1).\; a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c \quad\forall a,b,c \in G
  \\&(G_2).\; \exists e \in G \quad\text{such that}\quad a*e=e*a=a
  \\&(G_3).\; \forall a \in G, \exists b \in G 
              \quad\text{such that}\quad a*b=b*a=e
  \\&(G_4).\; a*b=b*a, \quad\forall a,b \in G
\end{align}$$
with the multiplication operation of complex numbers. How to develop $G$? As well $|z|=1$?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What have you done towards this problem so far? Do you know what the definition of an Abelian group is? What parts of the definition have you been able to show, and what parts have you not been able to show? Where did you get stuck on the parts that you were not able to show?

Comment: I know that group of properties as well as property that defines an Abelian group. I thought of taking an $x$ and $y$ belonging to $G$, but do not know how fit with the multiplication of complex numbers, let alone with $| z | = 1$. Tou little lost.

Comment: @DaniloSantana What about taking *the simple* path? $$z,w\in\Bbb G\implies |z|\,,\,\,|w|=1\implies |zw|=|z||w|=1\cdot1=1\implies zw\in G$$ and you have closedness. Inverse is as easy as the above, unit is trivial and associativity is inherited from $\;\Bbb C\;$ .

Comment: Even after your edit, you haven't shown any effort towards showing $G$ is a group yourself. Re-read qaphla's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to see that $|zw| = |z||w|$:

Let $z = a+ib$, and $w = c + id$. Then:

$|zw| = |(a+ib)(c+id)| = |(ac-bd) + i(ad+bc)| = \sqrt{(ac-bd)^2 + (ad+bc)^2}$

$= \sqrt{a^2c^2 - 2abcd + b^2d^2 + a^2d^2 + 2abcd + b^2c^2}$

$= \sqrt{a^2c^2 + a^2d^2 + b^2c^2 + b^2d^2} = \sqrt{a^2(c^2 + d^2) + b^2(c^2 + d^2)}$

$= \sqrt{(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2)} = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{c^2+d^2} = |z||w|$.

In particular, if $|z| = |w| = 1$, then $|zw| = |z||w| = 1\cdot 1 = 1$.

Note that $1 = 1+i0 \in G$, since $\sqrt{1^2 + 0^2} = \sqrt{1} = 1$.

Inverses are only slightly trickier:

if $z = a+ib$ is such that $|z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = 1$, then since:

$\dfrac{1}{z} = \dfrac{a}{a^2+b^2} + i\dfrac{-b}{a^2+b^2}$,

We see that $\left|\dfrac{1}{z}\right| = \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{a}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{-b}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2}$

$= \sqrt{\dfrac{a^2 + b^2}{(a^2 + b^2)^2}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{a^2 + b^2}} = \sqrt{1} = 1$,

so $\dfrac{1}{z} \in G$, if $G$ is.

---

Recall that we identify $z = a+ib$ with the element $(a,b) \in \Bbb R^2$, and define $|z| = \|(a,b)\|$, the Euclidean distance of $(a,b)$ from the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $z\in G$, there exists $\varphi\in(-\pi,\pi]$ with $z=e^{i\varphi}$.

(Of course one can choose $\varphi \in [0,2\pi)$ or $\varphi \in I$ for any half closed intervall $I$ of length $2\pi$).

Comment: Thinking about it, $\varphi\in\mathbb R$ is everything you need. This way one doesn't have to think about equivalence relation/classes that come up when talking about the argument of a complex number.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb C^{\times}$ is an Abelian group.

The map $z \mapsto |z|$ is a group homomorphism $\mathbb C^{\times} \to \mathbb R^{\times}$.

The circle is the kernel of this map and so is a subgroup of $\mathbb C^{\times}$.

The crucial point is that $|zw|=|z|\ |w|$ and this can be proved as follows: $$|zw|^2=(zw)(\overline{zw})=z w \bar z \bar w=z \bar z w \bar w = |z|^2\ |w|^2$$